# Property 'text' not found on object of type 'UIView'

Tags: objective-c

I want to send something from viewController to another viewController which I use NSNotification.

I defined button in first vc and I defined label in second vc. When I click button, I want to see number of click on label but it has problem. I receive an 'Property 'text' not found on object of type 'UIView' error.

How can I solve this?

**---firstVC.h---**

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)btnTap:(id)sender;

@end
```

**---firstVC.m---**

```
import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)btnTap:(id)sender {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"not" object:nil];
}
@end
```

**---secondVC.h---**

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *lbl;
@property int number;

@end
```

**---secondVC.m---**

```
import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize number,lbl;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationMethod:) name:@"not" object:nil];
    number=0;
}

-(void) notificationMethod :(NSNotificationCenter *) notification{

    number++;
    lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",number];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: What is `lbl`? can you show declaration of `lbl`?

Comment: Looks like you have declared `lbl` as `UIView`.

Comment: lbl is just the name of label in secondViewController @Ronak Chaniyara

Comment: Show code of `.h` file of secondViewController where you have declared it.

Comment: I wrote all codes in question, I wrote 'lbl' and when I write 'lbl.' I couldn't see 'text', I think text must come after 'lbl.'

Comment: i think you have mistakenly post wrong code for secondVC.h

Comment: Sorry, I post fvc.m's code instead of svc.h's and I edited.

Comment: have you solved issue?@Hüseyin Bakan

Answer (score 4):

Error you are getting comes only when you try to set text on `UIView`.

Because `UIView` doesn't have text property and you are trying to set text on `UIView`.

So, may be you have declared `lbl` as `UIView`, change it `UILabel` and check after that.

***EDIT:***

Replace in `secondVC.h`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *lbl;
```

With

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
```